# What is difficulty in blockchain?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, ethereumjs

If you want to start a private net with Geth, then you need to create a Genesis Block. You specify the attributes of this block through a config file. One of these configurations is 'difficulty'.

An example I've seen is this: `"difficulty": "0x0400"`.

My question is, what does this number represent?

Reference : [What does the difficulty value represent in a Geth genesis block config?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/21670/what-does-the-difficulty-value-represent-in-a-geth-genesis-block-config)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your linked question basically already has the answer. It's the (initial) difficulty of mining a block. It typically gets adjusted at constant intervals to keep the interval of blocks similar. The smaller the difficulty, the easier it is to mine a block.

Comment: Yes but I am still confuse .
Can you explain this term what exactly he means ?
difficulty": "0x0400

Comment: It's basically a number encoded in hexadecimal format. If it was `0x0001` (so, 1 in decimal), it will take approximately 1 hash to mine a block. So as soon as you complete one hash you succesfully "mine" the block and get a reward (in Ether) for doing so. If you're unsure how mining works, you should have a look at for example the Ethereum White Paper.